# Access variable defined in other file from class

Tags: php, variables, scope, global-variables, global

I would like to know if there is a way to access a variable defined in an other file from a class in PHP.

Example :

**file_01.php**

```
<?php
    $a = 42;
?>
```

**file_02.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('file_01.php');

    class mnyClass
    {
        private $myVar;

        function __construct($var = $a)
        {
            $this->myVar = $var;
        }

        function getVar()
        {
            return $this->var;
        }

        function setVar($var)
        {
            $this->myVar = $var;
        }
    }
?>
```

Obviously, my class is more complicated. I have chosen this example for a better comprehension of what I try to do ;)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, I thank you all for your answers. Indeed, I wanted to  set up application defaults, but with association arrays. The `define()` method does not take an array as parameter. I knew the `$GLOBALS` variable but it can't be used in constructor parameters : / So, I resign to use $GLOBALS in my constructor with NULL tests on parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the variable via GLOBALS:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

EDIT: a little more detail-

```
function __construct() {
  $this->myVar = $GLOBALS['a'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** do this:

```
    function __construct($var = $a)
    {
        $this->myVar = $var;
    }
```

What you can do is pass it:

```
<?php
    require_once('file_01.php');
    $mnyClass = new mnyClass($a);// the torch has been passed!

    class mnyClass
    {
        private $myVar;

        function __construct($var = null)
        {
            $this->myVar = $var;
        }

        function getVar()
        {
            return $this->var;
        }

        function setVar($var)
        {
            $this->myVar = $var;
        }
    }
?>
```

**OR** you can do this (it is **not** advisable):

```
    function __construct($var = null)
    {
        if($var === null) $var = $GLOBALS['a']; //use global $a variable
        $this->myVar = $var;
    }
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why is it not advisable?

Comment: @Frank you cannot scope global variables.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're setting up some application defaults. It might make sense to define these as constants:

file_01.php:

```
define('DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_A', 42);
```

file_02.php

```
class myClass
{
    function __construct($var = DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_A) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use this method :

```
<?php

require_once('file_01.php');

class myClass {

    private $myVar;

    function __construct($var = NULL)
    {
        global $a;

        if($var == NULL)
            $this->myVar = $a;
        else
            $this->myVar = $var; 
    }
}

?>
```

I declare my variable `$a` as global in the constructor, set the default value of my `$var` to **NULL** and check if the constructor was called with parameter(s) ($var == NULL).